# RavenDB - Is an index on a many to many relationship document more efficient than an index on a collection property?

Tags: c#, linq, indexing, lucene, ravendb

Say I have a group:

```
class Group {
    int Id
}
```

And a member:

```
class Member {
    int Id
    List<int> GroupIds
}
```

Either 1) A member could have this GroupIds property, and query like so

```
var groupMembers = session.Query<Member>().Where(m => m.GroupIds.Contains(groupId)
```

Or     2) I can define a GroupMember

```
class GroupMember {
    int GroupId
    int MemberId
    //Extra information
}

var groupMembers = session.Query<GroupMember>().Where(m => m.GroupId == groupId)
```

I have about 10,000,000 members and 1,000 groups, each group can have about 100,000 members, and each member might be part of 10 groups.

From a design view the first option is more desirable, but how performant is collection indexing in comparison to a normal property index?

Does this change if a member could be part of 100 or 1000 groups instead?

Comment: Why not use 

```
class Group {
   int Id;
   List<int> MemberIds;
}

class Member {
    int Id;
}
```

Comment: I had it to start with, but some of the extra information in GroupMember was MemberName which I need to be quickly available without joins, and with 100,000 members, the size of the document turned out to be 40mb, which was pretty difficult to download

Answer (score 1):

Create '**Groups**' Collection based on:

```
class Group { int GroupId; List<string> MemberDocs; }
```

And create '**Members**' Collection based on:

```
 class Member { int MemberId; string MemberName;}
```

And then create a Static-Index on the 'Groups' Collection:
With RQL such as:

```
from g in docs.Groups
select new {
   Group = g.GroupId,
   MembersNames = g.MemberDocs.Select(x => LoadDocument(x, "Members").MemberName)
}
```

Set the index field: '**MembersNames**' to be a *STORED* field

And then you can issue the following query:

```
from index 'Members' as g
where g.Group = 'some_group_id'
select {
   Names:  g.MemberNames
}
```

'Names' will contain all members in the specified group